# Java Webapp - Where to store Images

Tags: java, spring, image, heroku

I created a web application using Java Spring, Hibernate, with JSP's. It's basically a blog I made from scratch, so there's an interface where I can add a new blog post with pictures.

I use Heroku to host and deploy the app.

When I want to post images in a blog post, I do:

And that image is currently stored in a resource folder right outside of 'WEB-INF'. Except, as I add more blog posts, I will have a lot of large sized pictures. I don't know where I should store these images and how I should access it. I thought of storing it in the file system, but wouldn't I have to re-deploy the app on heroku each time I add more images? Another option was having a public dropbox folder and linking the images there, but that would open up my entire dropbox directory to the public. Is there a better way to do all of this, especially managing so many large pictures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Saving files in file system is not a scalable solution. If you add new servers for your web app the images won't be displayed correctly for any request.

You have to save your images in a distributed environment. It can be a LOB column on the database (Postgres for example) or an Amazon S3 storage system.

The access type is very different but both systems are a good option for your images. If they are big in size, S3 is the best option.

Comment: Ok, great! Yea I looked at Amazon S3 and it seems to be exactly what I wanted. I'll try that, thanks!

Comment: @Nicola You're right. Storing images in resources folder would increase size of app folder and in case of multiple application servers, images won't load properly. It's always better to use storage system like Amazon S3.

Comment: What about, say, architecture images for a README.md? Hotlinking to some external website is not recommended for many reasons, but more importantly it can result in broken images. If you don't store them internally, you could lose valuable information.