# Saving Images Spring boot Heroku

Tags: spring, spring-boot, file, heroku, file-upload

I'm trying to save images in src/resources/avatars/ folder on a Spring-Boot Server deployed on Heroku.
Everything is working fine when I upload the pictures on the server running locally on my computer (localhost) but after deploying, the request succeeds and I get no errors, but the file is not saved.

Can anyone help me on this ?
Here is the controller code for the upload.

```
@PostMapping("/uploadAvatar/{username}")
public String uploadAvatar(@RequestParam("imageFile") MultipartFile avatar, @PathVariable(value = "username") String username) {
    if (avatar.isEmpty()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Please load a file");
     }
 
     try {
         
         // Get the file and save it uploads dir
         byte[] bytes = avatar.getBytes();
         Path path = Paths.get("/app/src/main/resources/avatars/" + username + ".jpg");
         System.out.println(path.toString());
         System.out.println(path.getParent().toString());
         Files.write(path, bytes);
         System.out.println("Normally the picture is saved.");
     } catch (IOException e) {

         e.printStackTrace();
     }
 
     return "success";
    
}
```

My guess is that the problem is with the path, but I am new in Spring boot and this is the first time I am uploading files to a deployed server.

Comment: Even if you get this temporarily working, Heroku's ephemeral filesystem will lose the images frequently. You need to use a third-party service like Amazon S3 or Azure Blob Storage. There is plenty of material on this in Heroku's documentation, and here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Webapp - Where to store Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652024/java-webapp-where-to-store-images)

Comment: Well, if heroku is not the best solution for storing images then it can't be helped. Thanks

Comment: You're missing the point. This is a _deliberate architectural decision_ made by the Heroku folks. There are lots of benefits to doing things this way. You can still host on Heroku; you just can't store your uploads there.